# Angular wp-api cannot get headers for X_Total_Pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, resources, ionic-framework

I'm using Angular wp-api module and each time my $resource request responds I can see the ResponseHeaders in Chrome with X_Total_Pages and other header information.  But I cannot add them to the scope.

Here is my controller...

```
    .controller('newslettersController', ['$scope','$stateParams','$sce','WPFactory', function ($scope,$stateParams,$sce,WPFactory) {


$scope.newsletters = WPFactory.query({
    param1: 'posts',
    page: $scope.pageNum,
    'filter[cat]': 8,
    'filter[posts_per_page]' : 10,
    'filter[orderby]': 'ID'
}, function(data, reponseHeaders) {


$scope.header = reponseHeaders('X_Total_Pages');

 });
  });
    }]);
```

And my factory...

```
    .factory("WPFactory", function($resource) {
            var dataResponse = $resource('http://www.example.com/wp-json/:param1/:param2/:param3/:param4/:param6/:param7', {}, {
        get: {
      method: 'GET'
        }
            });
    return dataResponse;  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

is this jeffsebrings [angular module](https://github.com/jeffsebring/angular-wp-api)? If it is I think you need  to inject your service with wpAPIResource:

```
.factory("WPFactory", function($resource, wpAPIResource)
```

and use it to query the json rest api (wp-api).

Also, not sure if your controller is passing the query object quite right:

I would change up your factory something like this:

```
.factory("WPFactory", function(wpAPIResource) {

         var posts_query = function(args) {
             return wpAPIResource.query(args); 
         };

         return posts_query;
})
```